# gsub extract two words

Tags: r, gsub

I cannot get my head around `gsub()`. If text is:

```
 text <- "Genus_species_1652_NL"
```

How would I extract to get

```
"Genus species"
```

Thanks. This is a useful link but I havnt been able to sort it
http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/SvetlanaEdenRFiles/regExprTalk.pdf

Comment: Could you explain why you would use `gsub()` for this and not, e.g., `strsplit()`? What are the constraints you are working under?

Comment: And if you were to try `strsplit`, one option might be: `unlist(lapply(strsplit(text, "_",), "[", 1:2))`

Comment: @NickCrouch, could you please accept one as an answer, so that the question doesn't remain open? Both the answers clearly give what you've asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this like:

```
> gsub('([A-z]+)_([A-z]+)_.*', '\\1 \\2', text)
[1] "Genus species"
```

but as mentioned in a comment, a tool like strsplit may be more useful.

Comment: Thanks, I hadnt thought of looking at `strsplit` but will check it out